# can I use subquery in the inner join condition sql

Tags: sql

table (Trips)

```
| Id | Client_Id | Driver_Id | City_Id |     Status      |Request_at|


| 1  |     1     |    10     |    1    |     completed      |2013-10-01|

| 2  |     2     |    10     |    1    |     completed      |2013-10-02|

| 3  |     3     |    11     |    6    |     completed      |2013-10-03|
```

table ( users)

```
Users_Id    | Banned |  Role  |

|    1     |   No   | client |

|    2     |   Yes  | client |

|    3     |   No   | client |

|    4     |   No      | driver|
```

How can I join these 2 tables (trips, users) on the condition that the user role needs to be client and these clients should be unbanned.
I am trying to use a subquery but I got "single-row subquery returns more than one row"error and not sure what went wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM Trips
INNER JOIN users
ON client_id = (SELECT users_id from users 
                  where 
                  role = 'Client' and  banned = 'No');
```

Comment: You can simply add the conditions to the join

Answer (score 2):

No need for a sub-select, just put those conditions into the join condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Trips
  JOIN users ON trips.client_id = users.users_id 
            and users.role = 'Client' 
            and users.banned = 'No';
```

As that is an inner join, this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Trips
  JOIN users ON trips.client_id = users.users_id 
WHERE users.role = 'Client' 
  and users.banned = 'No';
```

This would **not** be different if you had used an outer join

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  the subquery
the join should be between Trips and Users eg  :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Trips
INNER JOIN users ON Trips.client_id = usres.users_id 
        and users.role = 'Client' 
        and  users.banned = 'No';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Trips
 INNER JOIN Users ON [Trips].Id = [Users].User_Id AND [Users].Role = 'client' AND [Users].Banned = 'No'
```

Comment: Square brackets are invalid in an SQL identifier and the question has not been tagged with any specific DBMS (that would allow this non-standard syntax)

Comment: I'm pretty sure square brackets are perfectly legal.  I use them in all my stored procedures to identify table names when joining tables.  This is how I personally format and write my SQL and it's perfectly valid syntax.  The question didn't have to request it.

Comment: They are **not** legal in "SQL" (the query language). The tag `sql` refers to ANSI SQL, not a specific DBMS product that might allow non-standard identifiers

Comment: Well he's clearly using SQL Server, which allows it, so why are you up in arms over a minor syntax preference that doesn't change my solution to him one bit?

Comment: From where do you take it that he is "clearly" using SQL Server? Plus: the tag info for the `sql` tag says: "*Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Trips
INNER JOIN users ON users.users_id = Trips.Client_ID
WHERE users.Banned = 'No' AND users.Role = 'client'
```